# Xpath to get prices on amazon

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Here's the URL first:

```
http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00EYCBFDQ/ref=s9_pop_gw_g147_i3?pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_r=1YP3T548XBFHJ1RA3EH8&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=402518447&pf_rd_i=1320006031
```

Above is the link to some product page on www.amazon.in.I want to get the actual price which is `Rs.4,094`. Below is a python code which tries to print the price and I have used `//span[@id="actualPriceValue"]/text()` to get the price but its returning an empty list.Can anyone suggest how to get the price?

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00EYCBFDQ/ref=s9_pop_gw_g147_i3?pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_r=1YP3T548XBFHJ1RA3EH8&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=402518447&pf_rd_i=1320006031')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
price = tree.xpath('//span[@id="actualPriceValue"]/text()')

print price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following XPath:

```
price = tree.xpath("//*[@id='actualPriceValue']/b/span/text()")[0]
```

The following code checks out:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00EYCBFDQ/ref=s9_pop_gw_g147_i3?pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_r=1YP3T548XBFHJ1RA3EH8&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=402518447&pf_rd_i=1320006031')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
price = tree.xpath("//*[@id='actualPriceValue']/b/span/text()")[0]

print price
```

Result:

```
4,094.00
[Finished in 3.0s]
```

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the `span` with id `actualPriceValue` doesn't have direct text. You'll want to do something like this (I am pulling it out of my head so you may have to alter it):

Edit: Fixed. Below explanation is still accurate.

```
//*[@id='actualPriceValue']/b/span/text()
```

You'll notice the HTML looks like this:

```
<span id="actualPriceValue">
    <b class="priceLarge">
       <span style="text-decoration: inherit; white-space: nowrap;">
           <span class="currencyINR">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
           <span class="currencyINRFallback" style="display:none">Rs. </span>
           4,112.00
       </span>
    </b>
</span>
```

You'll notice that it should be:

```
Span with an id of actualPriceValue -> first b element -> first span element -> text
```

Comment: I am still getting an empty list.

Comment: Yeah, I was syntactically a little bit off (missing the * and didn't need the [0]s). I see the above answer was similar, but not lacking in syntax! :)